# Why an additional async operation is making my code faster than when the operation is not taking place at all?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, entity-framework, asynchronous

I'm working on a SMS-based game (Value Added Service), in which a question must be sent to each subscriber on a daily basis. There are over 500,000 subscribers and therefore performance is a key factor. Since each subscriber can be a difference state of the competition with different variables, database must be queried separately for each subscriber before sending a text message. To achieve the best performance I'm using .Net Task Parallel Library (TPL) to spawn parallel threadpool threads and do as much async operations as possible in each thread to finally send texts asap.

Before describing the actual problem there are some more information necessary to give about the code.

At first there was no async operation in the code. I just scheduled some 500,000 tasks with the default task scheduler into the Threadpool and each task would work through the routines, blocking on all EF (Entity Framework) queries and sequentially finishing its job. It was good, but not fast enough. Then I changed all EF queries to Async, the outcome was superb in speed but there has been so many deadlocks and timeouts in SQL server that about a third of the subscribers never received a text! After trying different solutions, I decided not to do too many Async Database operations while I have over 500,000 tasks running on a 24 core server (with at least 24 concurrent threadpool threads)!
I rolled back all the changes (the Asycn ones) expect for one web service call in each task which remained Async.

Now the weird case:

In my code, I have a boolean variable named "isCrossSellActive". When the variable is set some more DB operations take place and an asycn webservice call will happen on which the thread awaits. When this variable is false, none of these operations will happen including the async webservice call. Awkwardly when the variable is set the code runs so much faster than when it's not! It seems like for some reason the awaited async code (the cooperative thread) is making the code faster.

Here is the code:

```
public async Task AutoSendMessages(...)
    {

        //Get list of subscriptions plus some initialization



        LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler lcts = new LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler(numberOfThreads);
        TaskFactory taskFactory = new TaskFactory(lcts);
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

        //....

        foreach (var sub in subscriptions)
        {
            AutoSendData data = new AutoSendData
            {
                ServiceId = serviceId,
                MSISDN = sub.subscriber,
                IsCrossSellActive = bolCrossSellHeader
            };

            tasks.Add(await taskFactory.StartNew(async (x) =>
            {
                await SendQuestion(x);
            }, data));
        }

        GC.Collect();

        try
        {
            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
        }
        catch (AggregateException ae)
        {
            ae.Handle((ex) =>
            {
                _logRepo.LogException(1, "", ex);
                return true;
            });
        }

        await _autoSendRepo.SetAutoSendingStatusEnd(statusId);
    }

public async Task SendQuestion(object data)
    {
        //extract variables from input parameter

        try
        {
            if (isCrossSellActive)
            {
                int pieceCount = subscriptionRepo.GetSubscriberCarPieces(curSubscription.service, curSubscription.subscriber).Count(c => c.isConfirmed);

                foreach (var rule in csRules)
                {
                    if (rule.Applies) 
                    {
                        if (await HttpClientHelper.GetJsonAsync<bool>(url, rule.TargetServiceBaseAddress))
                        {
                            int noOfAddedPieces = SomeCalculations();

                            if (noOfAddedPieces > 0)
                            {
                            crossSellRepo.SetPromissedPieces(curSubscription.subscriber, curSubscription.service,
                                    rule.TargetShortCode, noOfAddedPieces, 0, rule.ExpirationLimitDays);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
// The rest of the code. (Some db CRUD)
await SmsClient.SendSoapMessage(subscriber, smsBody);
        }
catch (Exception ex){//...}
}
```

Comment: How do you know it runs *so much faster*? Have you profiled your app?

Comment: "await taskFactory.StartNew(async" It's probably this. I refuse to look at this code any further. Too long. Closing now with the respective close reason. You need to make it easy to help you. This could be a good and interesting question but right now it's unanalyzable.

Comment: how did you benchmark your app

Comment: First of all sorry for the long code, description, i tried to shorten the code as much as possible. This is my first time asking question on stackoverflow. @yuval I run this code on the server sending data to over half a milion subscribers. The code with the asycn webservice call included, takes about 2 hours to send text to all subscribers, and without it, takes over 8 hours!!

Comment: `GC.Collect();` don't do this

Comment: @user3909940 I just voted for reopening, thanks for the edit.

Comment: Thanks @usr. Your comment on "await taskFactory.StartNew(async ...)" was good. I changed the code removing the first await and right after that the code behavior changed but not necessarily in a good way. In the beginning the system sends texts so fast. Over 150 texts per second. The it rapidly slows down to about 10! Resource monitor shows very rapid changes in network bandwidth consumption. The plot shows a pulse function like behavior. It's good to mention that the awaited webservice is hosted on the same server thus not consuming any network bandwidth.

Comment: The actual bandwidth usage must be related to the last line of code (await SmsClient.SendSoapMessage()). I set the Max threadpool size to 20 and also limited the taskFactory concurrency level to 10. but it does not seem to make significant changes. Actually changing threadpool size and also changing the task scheduler's concurrency level to any number does not seem to change this behavior. I use a custom taskscheduler to be able to limit the concurrency level. You can see the full implementation of this custom scheduler here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, thanks to @usr and the clue he gave me, the problem is finally solved!
His comment drew my attention to the awaited taskFactory.StartNew(...) line which sequentially adds new tasks to the "tasks" list which is then awaited on by Task.WaitAll(tasks);

At first I removed the await keyword before the taskFactory.StartNew() and it led the code towards a horrible state of malfunction! I then returned the await keyword to before taskFactory.StartNew() and debugged the code using breakpoints and amazingly saw that the threads are ran one after another and sequentially before the first thread reaches the first await inside the "SendQuestion" routine. When the "isCrossSellActive" flag was set despite the more jobs a thread should do the first await keyword is reached earlier thus enabling the next scheduled task to run. But when its not set the only await keyword is the last line of the routine so its most likely to run sequentially to the end.

usr's suggestion to remove the await keyword in the for loop seemed to be correct but the problem was the Task.WaitAll() line would wait on the wrong list of `Task<Task<void>>` instead of `Task<void>`. I finally used Task.Run instead of TaskFactory.StartNew and everything changed. Now the service is working well. The final code inside the for loop is:

```
tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await SendQuestion(data);
            }));
```

and the problem was solved.
Thank you all.

P.S. Read this article on Task.Run and why TaskFactory.StartNew  is dangerous: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html

Comment: one other thing to think about that might help you out.  You mentioned getting deadlocks in the DB when trying to make 500,000 individual selections.  Would it be possible to write a query that returns all the data you need in a single selection?  If so, you could have your data access yield return an IEnumerable so you could do your parallel processing as you read from the db with a single read.

Comment: There is a problem here. The sending process takes so long that a subscribers state is highly likely to change which make previous query results obsolete. Me and my team tried to do so many optimizations and that was of course one of the main things we considered. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

It's extremly hard to tell unless you add some profiling that tell you which code is taking longer now.

Without seeing more numbers my best guess would be that the SMS service doesn't like when you send too many requests in a short time and chokes. When you add the extra DB calls the extra delay make the sms service work better.

A few other small details:

await Task.WhenAll is usually a bit better than Task.WaitAll. WaitAll means the thread will sit around waiting. Making a deadlock slightly more likely.

Instead of:

```
        tasks.Add(await taskFactory.StartNew(async (x) =>
        {
            await SendQuestion(x);
        }, data));
```

You should be able to do

```
        tasks.Add(SendQuestion(data));
```